# Do something javascript before asp.net anypostback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I wanna do something in javascript before page goes for post back.

How to run a javascript function before any asp.net postback?

```
$('form').submit(function () {
      alert('hello');
});
```

It doesn't work... :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I find the way, in the [asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/p/1402658/3043195.aspx) and it was a some code in codebehind.

Just add this to your Page_Load event handler, changing the javaScript string to what you want to happen.

```
string scriptKey = "OnSubmitScript";
string javaScript = "alert('RegisterOnSubmitStatement fired');";
this.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), scriptKey, javaScript);
```

Comment: +1 I know how old this is, but thank you so much! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do something client-side *before* asp's postback, try using the `OnClientClick` attribute of the `asp:button`, eg:

```
<asp:Button OnClick="submit" OnClientClick="myPrePostbackFunction()" Text="Submit" runat="server" ... />
```

Comment: i know that, but i have lots of asp element on page , i want to do this code before any postback, not for a special button or element

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    return confirm('you sure?');
});
```

The form won't be submitted unless you return `true` and before that you can do all you want.
It doesn't have to be a `confirm()` call of course.

Comment: Quite odd, what browser are you using to test?

Answer (score 1):

In year 2021, I'm completey getting rid of jQuery. To do this, I add to my page javascript:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', e => {
if (conditionPreventingPostBack) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
    <form name="someform">
    <input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.someform.onsubmit = function  ( e ) {
    e = e|| window.event;
    if ( !confirm ( "sure?") ){
        e.returnValue ? ( e.returnValue = false ):  e.preventDefault();
    }
}
// then jquery version
$("form").bind("submit", function  ( e ) {
    if ( !confirm ( "sure?" ) ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
</script>
```